Even after making backgroundHandler a top level function still throwing an error as needs to be either a static function or a top level function
I tried both as making  firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler   to a top level function and then tried with making it as static. In both the cases it throws the same error as it needs to be either a static function or a top level function.
My backgroundHandler method looks like below:
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {...}

then I call it as
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

It throws error every time when app gets opened from terminated state. But when app is running in background and notification comes, firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler block gets visited and on tapping on notification it opens the app. It doesn't throw error in this case.
please suggest solution to get over this error.

Top level functions are functions that are not encapsulated within any class, declare it outside any class, if you prefer to put it as a method inside a class ensure making it static method.
And btw, try to make its return type just void not Future<void>
// Define the background handler as a top-level function
void backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message)async{
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
  // Perform background task here
}

and register the background handler in the main function:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Register the background handler
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);

  runApp(MyApp());
}

